# Pass orignal IP in Google Cloud network load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

We are using Google Cloud's "[Network load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/example)" to send our visitors to one of our 3 different application servers.

Problem is the request IP address the application sees is the IP address of the load balancer. This is how a load balancer works, I get that.

Is there a way to tell the network load balancer to pass on the original IP? In a separate header maybe?

Thank you!